# c++ memory leak in leetcode add two numbers

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

trying to do leetcode challenges using C++, a newbie here.

below is my code

```cpp
/** Problem 2, Add two numbers, done 04/07/2021


You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

Example 1:

Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
Output: [7,0,8]
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

Example 2:

Input: l1 = [0], l2 = [0]
Output: [0]

Example 3:

Input: l1 = [9,9,9,9,9,9,9], l2 = [9,9,9,9]
Output: [8,9,9,9,0,0,0,1]

Constraints:

    The number of nodes in each linked list is in the range [1, 100].
    0 <= Node.val <= 9
    It is guaranteed that the list represents a number that does not have leading zeros.
*/

#include "../common_headers.hpp"

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *nxt) : val(x), next(nxt){}
};

ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2){
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* node = new ListNode();
    head = node;
    int carry = 0;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    while (l1 != nullptr || l2 != nullptr) {
        if(l1 != nullptr){
            v1 = l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        } else v1 = 0;
        if(l2 != nullptr) {
            v2 = l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        } else v2 = 0;

        int sum = v1 + v2 + carry;
        if(sum > 9){
            sum = sum % 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
        ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(sum);
        node->next = newNode;
        node = node->next;
    }
    if(carry == 1){
        ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(1);
        node->next = newNode;
    }
    return head->next;
}

int main(){
    ListNode* n3 = new ListNode(3);
    ListNode* n2 = new ListNode(4, n3);
    ListNode* n1 = new ListNode(2, n2);

    ListNode* m3 = new ListNode(4);
    ListNode* m2 = new ListNode(6, m3);
    ListNode* m1 = new ListNode(5, m2);

    ListNode* ln = addTwoNumbers(n1, m1);
    
    while (ln != nullptr){
        std::cout<<ln->val<<" ";
        ln = ln->next;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and give me the correct answer, however, g++ told me there's memory leaks. I understand that I used new operator here, but I cannot delete them before I get my returned answer.

How can I fix this issue please? below is the error message

```
==3256==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff9d68f40a7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xb00a7)
    #1 0x401295 in addTwoNumbers(ListNode*, ListNode*) /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:43
    #2 0x4016d8 in main /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:84
    #3 0x7ff9d62f0b74  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff9d68f40a7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xb00a7)
    #1 0x4015c0 in main /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:78
    #2 0x7ff9d62f0b74  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff9d68f40a7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xb00a7)
    #1 0x40169c in main /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:82
    #2 0x7ff9d62f0b74  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)

Indirect leak of 48 byte(s) in 3 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff9d68f40a7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xb00a7)
    #1 0x401323 in addTwoNumbers(ListNode*, ListNode*) /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:64
    #2 0x4016d8 in main /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:84
    #3 0x7ff9d62f0b74  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff9d68f40a7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xb00a7)
    #1 0x401652 in main /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:81
    #2 0x7ff9d62f0b74  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff9d68f40a7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xb00a7)
    #1 0x401606 in main /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:80
    #2 0x7ff9d62f0b74  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff9d68f40a7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xb00a7)
    #1 0x401576 in main /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:77
    #2 0x7ff9d62f0b74  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff9d68f40a7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xb00a7)
    #1 0x40152c in main /home/xxx/Documents/Projects/leetcode/0001-0100/0002_Add_Two_Numbers.cpp:76
    #2 0x7ff9d62f0b74  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)
```

Comment: This can be solved by calling `delete` on all of the `ListNode`s that have been created using `new` in `main()` once the calculation is finished and before returning.  Even though they will be destroyed by the programming finishing once `main()` is complete, it is good practice to delete those variables, particularly if they have a user defined destructor.

Comment: Thank you, Can I have a follow up question please? Yes, this solve my problem, but on leetcode, I only need to write the function, no need to write the main. that means all the node I created in the addTwoNumbers function cannot be deleted as I don't know how the other part of the program handles with this. In order to avoid this memory leak problem is that a way to complete avoid using the new operate?

Comment: @B.Hong I have almost the same issue here! I tried using `vector<ListNode>` as member variables of the `solution` class, all for avoiding manual memory management. The code works perfectly fine offline, but the OJ engine may somehow messed with it. Please see [my discussion](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/1908501/heap-use-after-free-in-LeetCode-but-perfectly-fine-when-run-offline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete it at the end of main. After for loop but before "return 0;".
Main should look like this:

```
int main(){
    ...
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    delete n3;
    delete n2;
    delete n1;

    delete m3;
    delete m2;
    delete m1;

    ListNode* tmp;
    while (lnHead != nullptr) {
        tmp = lnHead;
        lnHead = lnHead->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the addTwoNumbers like this:

```
...
ListNode* tmp = head->next;
delete head;
return tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you, Can I have a follow up question please? Yes, this solve my problem, but on leetcode, I only need to write the  function, no need to write the main. that means all the node I created in the addTwoNumbers function cannot be deleted as I don't know how the other part of the program handles with this. In order to avoid this memory leak problem is that a way to complete avoid using the new operate?

Comment: I don't know any workaround for this. You can use the longer input list as the output list (it is possible you will need to add additional node) but this memory still needs to be freed outside of your function.